# Charm 4.0.1 Dialog NPE when called twice

Tags: gluon, gluon-mobile

On Charm 3.0.0 it was possible to instantiate a `Dialog` once and call `showAndWait` several times. On Charm 4.0.1 calling dialog.showAndWait() twice causes a NPE. So do we have to reinitialize a Dialog each time when we want to show it?

```
public class MyApp extends MobileApplication {

    private Dialog<ButtonType> dialog;

    @Override
    public void init() {

        addViewFactory(HOME_VIEW, () ->
        {
            initDialog();

            Button button = new Button("Show dialog");
            button.setOnAction(event -> dialog.showAndWait());

            return new View(button);
        });

    }

    private void initDialog() {
        dialog = new Dialog<>();
        dialog.setTitle(new Label("This is a regular dialog"));
        dialog.setContent(new Label("Just a regular dialog, plain and simple"));

        Button okButton = new Button("OK");
        okButton.setOnAction(e ->
        {
            dialog.hide();
        });

        dialog.getButtons().add(okButton);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: Is this behaviour intended or is it a bug, because the NPE wasn't there on the previous Charm version

Comment: Thanks for reporting. I've filed an issue on this. The main reason for this issue is the dialog layer being removed from the GlassPane after it was used the first time. For now it is safe to init the dialog all over again.